# ASP button control firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

The problem im having is a little complicated to explain, so please bear with me. I have 2 button controls. In the page load, I wanted to know what button created a postback on the page load. Through research I have found this snippet below and it works as expected. So here is my scenario of events that occur when click on the button.

```
   1. Click the button does a postback
   2. Runs the function below and tell me the id of the button
   3. Runs the clicked event handlers for that button

     Protected Sub btnCalc_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles  btnCalc.Click
          ' Do this
     End Sub
```

The problem comes in when I click the second button, it does steps 1 and 2 but NEVER DOES 3. Through testing, I have that it only does 1, 2, and 3 on the first button clicked. I have no clue why this is happening?

```
     Function GetPostBackControlName() As String

      Dim control As Control = Nothing
      Dim ctrlname As String = Page.Request.Params("__EVENTTARGET")

    If ctrlname <> Nothing AndAlso ctrlname <> [String].Empty Then
        control = Page.FindControl(ctrlname)
    Else
        Dim ctrlStr As String = [String].Empty
        Dim c As Control = Nothing

        For Each ctl As String In Page.Request.Form

            c = Page.FindControl(ctl) 

           If TypeOf c Is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button Then
                control = c
                Exit For
           End If

        Next

    End If

    Try
        Return control.ID.ToString
    Catch
        Return ""
    End Try

    End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried assigning separate Click event handlers? that way you know what button was clicked.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is, that paragraph just seems to go all over the place.  Also, that's a very poor use of a try/catch block.  You should check for expected conditions explicitly, not rely on an exception and just ignore the exception.  Try/catch isn't for control flow.

Comment: I hope this better explanation helps you understands my problem david

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250956/button-control-not-firing

Answer (score 1):

You really should look into just assigning `Click` event handlers to your buttons. Asp.net was designed purposely so that you wouldn't have to parse through the request object like you are doing above.