# Button control not firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

The problem im having is a little complicated to explain, so please bear with me. I have 2 button controls. In the page load, I wanted to know what button created a postback on the page load. Through research I have found this snippet below and it works as expected. So here is my scenario of events that occur when click on the button.

```
   1. Click the button does a postback
   2. Runs the function below and tell me the id of the button
   3. Runs the clicked event handlers for that button

     Protected Sub btnCalc_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles  btnCalc.Click
          ' Do this
     End Sub
```

The problem comes in when I click the second button, it does steps 1 and 2 but NEVER DOES 3. Through testing, I have that it only does 1, 2, and 3 on the first button clicked. I have no clue why this is happening?

```
     Function GetPostBackControlName() As String

      Dim control As Control = Nothing
      Dim ctrlname As String = Page.Request.Params("__EVENTTARGET")

    If ctrlname <> Nothing AndAlso ctrlname <> [String].Empty Then
        control = Page.FindControl(ctrlname)
    Else
        Dim ctrlStr As String = [String].Empty
        Dim c As Control = Nothing

        For Each ctl As String In Page.Request.Form

            c = Page.FindControl(ctl) 

           If TypeOf c Is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button Then
                control = c
                Exit For
           End If

        Next

    End If

    Try
        Return control.ID.ToString
    Catch
        Return ""
    End Try

    End Function
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't just wire the buttons directly to the event handler and use the `sender` parameter to get the button that was clicked? Its what its there for after all... AS for the question of why its not working it sounds like if 2 is working and you are getting the right ID then your problem is with step 3 which you don't seem to have shown us the code for.

Comment: Yes b/c im have dynamic tables that I dont want to rebuild everytime i do a postback. It slow down my page. It finds the ID when I step through it in the debugger, but it doesnt fire the last click event handler

Comment: @Will: If you want to only (re)load part of the page, consider the Microsoft AJAX UpdatePanel control that comes with Visual Studio. What version of Visual Studio are you using? You should also review your past questions and mark them as answered, as appropriate.